# Accessing a `var` passed as `inout` is undefined behavior?

Tags: swift, pass-by-reference, semantics, swift4, inout

From the [documentation for `inout` parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545):

> In-out parameters are passed as follows:
>
> 1. When the function is called, the value of the argument is copied.
> 2. In the body of the function, the copy is modified.
> 3. When the function returns, the copy’s value is assigned to the original argument.

From just this description, I would assume that modification of a variable passed as an `inout` parameter, within the scope in which it is passed as `inout`, is meaningless, since the original variable is guaranteed to be overwritten after the call returns. As a contrived example:

```
var x: Int = 5

({ (inoutX: inout Int) in
    inoutX = 7
    x = 6
})(&x)

print(x) // Expecting "7"
```

The original variable `x` is accessible through mutating capture, so it can still be assigned to. The expected printout is "7", since that is the value of `inoutX` at the end of the function call. But if I run this in the Swift 4 REPL, I actually get "6"!

The documentation sheds some light on this behavior:

> As an optimization, when the argument is a value stored at a physical address in memory, the same memory location is used both inside and outside the function body.

But then follows with a statement which is very clearly inaccurate:

> The optimized behavior is known as call by reference; it satisfies all of the requirements of the copy-in copy-out model while removing the overhead of copying.

Clearly, the optimized behavior is not satisfying the call-by-value-result convention which `inout` parameters claim to conform to. The documentation then acknowledges this, but in the reverse, explaining why you should not rely on *call-by-reference* behavior:

> Write your code using the model given by copy-in copy-out, without depending on the call-by-reference optimization, so that it behaves correctly with or without the optimization.
>
> Do not access the value that was passed as an in-out argument, even if the original argument is available in the current scope. When the function returns, your changes to the original are overwritten with the value of the copy. Do not depend on the implementation of the call-by-reference optimization to try to keep the changes from being overwritten.

What I can gather then, is that `inout` parameters are call-by-value-result, except when they're call-by-reference. And, based on how much the documentation doesn't want you to rely on call-by-reference semantics, I can only guess that the optimization is not performed in a well-defined set of cases. And if that's the case, then I can only conclude that *accessing a variable passed as `inout` parameter, within the scope in which it is `inout`, is undefined behavior.*

That's a relatively unfortunate conclusion, and I'm left confused by how unwilling the documentation is to make it. Why would it try to present `inout` parameters as obeying a particular calling convention, when (aside from setters or property observers) the semantics of these calling conventions are not observable in a defined manner? It's confusing enough that I doubt my own conclusion here, and so comes the question: is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. In Swift 4 (Xcode 9 GM) it aborts with the error message `Simultaneous accesses to 0x1005e3ec0, but modification requires exclusive access.`

Comment: As of Swift 3, `inout` parameters are always compiled as pass-by-references, which explains the behaviour you see. However they (generally) have the *semantics* of copy-in copy-out, and that's how you should treat them (for example, there's no guarantee whatsoever that the reference to the variable passed will remain valid after the call ends). Your code is a perfect example of why the exclusive access law was introduced in Swift 4; it prevents the writing of such code that's difficult to reason about. As Martin says, dynamic enforcement will catch this overlapping access at runtime and trap.

Comment: @MartinR Although it's not undefined behaviour anymore given runtime enforcement prevents it from happening :) Whether or not it was undefined behaviour *before* is an interesting question; I'm actually not too convinced that it was, given that one of the motivations of [SE-0176](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md) was "*Therefore, because of overlap, the compiler must pessimistically assume that each of these method calls might somehow find a way to modify the original variable that `set` was bound to*" and ...

Comment: from the [ownership manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md): 
"*Swift today allows nested accesses to the same variable; for example, a single variable can be passed as two different `inout` arguments, or a method can be passed a callback that somehow accesses the same variable that the method was called on. Doing this is mostly discouraged, but it's not forbidden, and both the compiler and the standard library have to bend over backwards to ensure that the program won't misbehave too badly if it happens.*"....

Comment: Therefore I'd guess that because the compiler made these pessimistic assumptions, it was likely defined (but not specified) behaviour. Although that being said, it did violate the copy-in copy-out semantics of `inout`.